# Hidining Badge option in Settings --> Notification for IOS 5.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, push-notification

In IOS 5, how do we hide the option of Push Notification badges to set by the users in the settings application. Before IOS 5.0, the below piece of code used to do the trick & my app never used to listen to badges. But in IOS badges option always comes. Any clue?

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the app from your phone, restarting your phone, and then run the app from xCode on your phone.